# jQuery imgAreaSelect Hiding with jqModal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqmodal, img-area-select-jquery

Trying to hide my imgAreaSelect selection area when my jqModal window closes. I had to do some z-index fixing to get this to work inside the jqModal window, but the selection area doesn't disappear and I'm left with a large black overlay. Unfortunately calling the imgAreaSelect to hide isn't working for some reason..

This is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ias;
    $().ready(function() {
       ias = $('#prevImage').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '9:6', instance: true });
       $('#cropImg').jqm({modal: true, trigger: '.showCrop'});
    });
    hideSelect() {
       ias.setOptions({ hide: true });
       ias.update();
    }
</script>
<input type="button" class="showCrop">
<div id="cropImg">
        <img  border="0" src="IMAGES/preview.png" width="590" id="prevImage" /> 
        <input type="button" onclick="hideSelect();" href="" class="jqmClose" value="Cancel">
</div>
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

`ias.cancelSelection()` should work if I understood your question correctly.